# How to change the default kernel Wi-Fi driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, intel

Ubuntu: 20.04.3

Kernel: 5.15.13

Motherboard: MSI Pro Z690-A WIFI (MS-7D25)

Processor: I9 12900k

Wifi 6: Intel Onboard (ax211 im not sure)

The kernel recognizes wifi and bluetooth. Neither one is doing 100% well. The bluetooth is cut or very low volume in the music. The wifi, you can hardly navigate.

Download some drivers from this official intel page: https://www.intel.la/content/www/xl/es/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

When I download the drivers I put them in `/lib/firmware`

Although the model that I think I have of a wifi card does not appear specifically, I can't change the driver that the default kernel brings to which I want to test to see if they work better.

How could I do that?

```
sudo lshw | grep iw
             configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.13-051513-generic firmware=64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.uc ip=192.168.1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.1
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has two supported kernel stacks; neither of which provide the 5.15 kernel so are you using Ubuntu?  (at 20.04.3 they are 5.11 [HWE] or 5.4 [GA], edge or 20.04.4's is 5.13 etc..)

Comment: Can you double-check your Ubuntu version? AFAIK 20.04.03 doesn't exist. Did you mean 20.04.3? You can [edit] your question to clarify

Comment: I already fixed the ubuntu version. Yes, I am using ubuntu, the version is now correctly indicated. I am using the kernel placed in the description because the LTS kernels did not recognize the wifi card, the bluetooth or the hdmi.

Comment: Why not use *edge* or 5.13 which is the next supported kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  As you're using a *unsupported* kernel (*taking on updates, security-patches yourself instead of using supplied updates*) specific details on how you changed your kernel maybe helpful (ie. did you add a Ubuntu *testing* kernel? or what?)

Comment: Use Mainline-gtk for the update. I updated it because the hardware is quite new and it was not supported in the supported LTS kernels

Comment: You might want to read the [wiki on mainline kernels](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) - they are intended for testing only which may explain the problems you are continuing to have.  Did you actually try the HWE kernel or did you only use the GA kernel? Also, have you tried Ubuntu 21.10? You can "Try Ubuntu" from installation media to see if things work without having to change your installed system until you're ready

Comment: You downloaded firmware, not a driver as is confirmed here: "I put them in /lib/firmware" Installing an older firmware version is unlikely to help anything. I would much rather troubleshoot why the wireless "The wifi, you can hardly navigate." Also, find the exact description of your wireless with: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you very much for the welcome. You are right, it is a firmware not a driver. Thanks for that. I agree with you, there is no point in looking for an older firmware.

`sudo lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

`Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7af0] (rev 11)
 DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi`

Comment: Let's troubleshoot the wireless: Please run: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Paste the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 With this code that you gave me, it is already confirmed that I have an ax211 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/M6vTH6xRh8/

Answer (score 1):

> IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                      MODE   CHAN  RATE
>
> - ```
>     xx:43:63:B0:7C:xx  POJA-F-2.4G               Infra  7     130 Mbit/s  >
>   ```

I doubt that you selected channel 7 for your router as it is an overlapped channel. https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11/

I strongly suspect that your router is still set to factory defaults; however, many wireless drivers, including *iwlwifi* benefit from fixed, not autoselect settings.

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Moreover, you have a very modern wireless device that is easily capable of very high speeds that is connected to the oldest, slowest protocol; that is 2.4 gHz. I am certain that you will have much better luck connected, again with specific settings, to a 5 gHz router.

**EDIT**: I suggest that you connect to the 5 gHz segment of your router only. The autoselect feature of your router may steer you to the stronger, but slower 2.4 gHz segment but you can defeat that by renaming the segments, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5. Then, only connect to myrouter5.

Next, please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Also, select a channel that is away from those used by your nearby neighbors; check:

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

In my case, a few neighbors are on channels 36 and 44. I therefore chose channel 149.

After making any changes in the router, reboot it.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: I really appreciate the time and the answer you are offering me. I read everything you sent me (links) and they helped me understand several things. I would like if possible, that you recommend the configuration for the 5Ghz network, the router allows it and my device also, so I would like to make the change. Finally I would like to consult you, why is it important to set the country where I am? Thank you so much for everything

Comment: One more thing ,Could I have made my wireless device work without upgrading the kernel that I did?

Comment: I believe that a kernel update was required. It might have worked with 5.14 but works well with 5.15. I shall add some details concerning 5 gHz as an edit soon. CRDA is often helpful because channel arrangements are different by country. As one example, channels 12-14 are legal in some parts of the world but not the USA. It is often helpful to make certain that both your router and your wireless device are on the same terms.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I await your comment on the 5ghz network.

Comment: Please see my EDIT above.

Comment: I am already working with the 5ghz network with your advice and it is doing very very well at the moment, thank you very much for everything!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected.